# Unable to hide nested tabNavigator's tabBar in react-navigation

Tags: react-navigation

I have a nested `tabNavigator` inside of another `tabNavigator`, and I'm trying to get the inner `tabNavigator`'s tabBar to be hidden. (The one below that shows "Map" and "list"). I'd like to keep the main `tabNavigator` which reads "Map Favorites Add a Site More".

[image]

The code which is rendering it this way is below:

```js
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
            login: {
                screen: LoginScreen
            },
            main: {
                screen: TabNavigator({
                    search: {
                        screen: TabNavigator({
                            map: {
                                screen: MapScreen
                            },
                            list: {
                                screen: ListScreen
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    favorites: {screen: FavoritesScreen},
                    addSite: {screen: AddSiteScreen},
                    more: {screen: MoreScreen}
                })
            },
            filter: {
                screen: FilterScreen,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarVisible: false
                }
            }
        }, {
            lazy: true
        });
```

I've tried adding

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false
}
```

to the `search` item as shown below:

```
search: {
    screen: TabNavigator({
        map: {
            screen: MapScreen
        },
        list: {
            screen: ListScreen
        }
    },
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarVisible: false
    })
}
```

but it ends up hiding the outermost `TabNavigator` (the one which reads "Map Favorites Add a Site More") instead of the inner one as I'd expect. (Image below)

[image]

Finally, out of ideas and thinking maybe it needs to be nested in as far as possible, I've also tried adding the

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false
}
```

to the innermost `map` and `list` items as such:

```
                search: {
                    screen: TabNavigator({
                        map: {
                            screen: MapScreen,
                            navigationOptions: {
                                tabBarVisible: false
                            }
                        },
                        list: {
                            screen: ListScreen,
                            navigationOptions: {
                                tabBarVisible: false
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
```

but the result of this is hiding both of the `TabNavigator`s and there are none at all. Am I missing something simple on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up finding a good answer to this question, and it seems like it might be a limitation of the library.

As a workaround (which works just as well), I decided instead of having three distinct screens: `SearchScreen`, `MapScreen`, and `ListScreen`, I just went down to only having one screen `SearchScreen`, and when that screen renders, it calls a component to render inside of it.

The navigation portion is now much flatter and looks like this:

```js
            main: {
                screen: TabNavigator({
                    search: {screen: SearchScreen},
                    favorites: {screen: FavoritesScreen},
                    addSite: {screen: AddSiteScreen},
                    more: {screen: MoreScreen}
                })
            }
```

Then inside of the `SearchScreen`, I just render the components (instead of treating them as their own distinct screens)

```js
renderSearchScreen = () => {
        const {viewStyle, lastKnownRegion, mapLoaded, sites} = this.props;

        if (viewStyle === map.SearchOptions.MAP) {
            return (
                <SearchMap
                    lastKnownRegion={lastKnownRegion}
                    mapLoaded={mapLoaded}
                    updateRegion={this.props.updateRegion}
                    sites={sites}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <SearchList
                    sites={sites}
                />
            );
        }

    };
```

After these changes, it's worked fine with no issues. I suppose it's also cleaner, and more logical from an architecture standpoint that `Map` and `List` be components that are nested and rendered instead of them also being distinct screens.

Hopefully this can help anyone else who runs into a similar issue with nested `TabNavigator`s!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in adding the navigationOptions with a property of tabBarVisible: false. However, you want to add it as a property to the tabNavigator, not to the screen itself like so:

```
search: {
screen: TabNavigator({
    map: {
        screen: MapScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    list: {
        screen: ListScreen
    }
}, navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false
});
```

}

One thing I want to point out is that lazy: true was deprecated in react-navigation version 23, so unless you are on version 22 or below that won't do anything.

Comment: I just tried your solution to double check my logic; if I do it the way you suggested, I still only get the outermost `TabNavigator` to disappear, not the inner one with `map` and `list`. Thanks for the heads up about lazy.